# jquery ajax not parsing json data from php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I'm facing a strange problem for the last 10 hours and its really very annoying. The problem is with jquery printing json data from php. The php script is running fine, but when the ajax call returns in complete: event i'm not getting any valid otput.

here is the jquery code::

```
list_choice = "A";
content_choice = "Artists";             //globals to store default value

$(document).ready(function() {
$('.list-nav > a').click(function() {
    var ltext = $(this).text();
    list_choice = ltext;
    console.log(ltext+" <------>    ");        
    $.ajax({            
        url: 'retrieveFileFront.php',
        data: {type: content_choice, navtext: list_choice},
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',            
        complete: function(data) {                
            console.log(data['message']['Album_Name']);          
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

});

i had to use complete: event as success: didn't worked at all. Atleast i'm getting some sort of output from the complete: event, although its giving `undefined` or `[object][Object]` which is totally ridiculous.

here is the `retrieveFileFront.php`:

```
<?php

require './retrieveFiles.php';

$type = $_POST['type'];
$nav_text = $_POST['navtext'];

$ret_files = new retrieveFiles($type, $nav_text);
$data = $ret_files->retFiles();
if ($data['success'] == FALSE) {
    $data = array('success' => FALSE, 'message' => 'Sorry an Error has occured');
    echo json_encode($data);

} else {
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

?>

and here is the `/retrieveFiles.php`

```
<?php

class retrieveFiles {        
    public $content_type;
    public $list_nav;
    public $connection;
    public $result;
    public $result_obj;
    public $tags_array;
    public $query;
    public $row;

    public function __construct($type, $nav_text) {            
        $this->content_type = $type;
        $this->list_nav = $nav_text;     
    }

    public function retFiles() {

        @$this->connection = new mysqli('localhost', 'usr', 'pass', 'data');
        if(!$this->connection) {
            die("Sorry Database connection could not be made please try again later. Sorry for the inconvenience..");
        }

        if ($this->content_type == "Artists") {                

            $this->query = "SELECT album_name, album_art FROM album_dummy NATURAL JOIN album_images_dummy WHERE artist_name LIKE '$this->list_nav%'";               

            try {
                $this->result = $this->connection->query($this->query);
                $this->row = $this->result->fetch_row();

                if (isset($this->row[0]) && isset($this->row[1])) {
                    $this->tags_array = array("success" => true, "message" => array("Album_Name" => $this->row[0], "Album_Art" => $this->row[1]));

                    return $this->tags_array;
                }

        }   catch (Exception $e) {                
                echo 'Sorry an Error has occurred'.$e;
                return false;
            }
        }
   }

}
```

?>

I'm getting a 200 response in console in firebug, which indicates that its running okay.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
```

`{"success":true,"message":{"Album_Name":"Streetcleaner","Album_Art":"\/var\/www\/html\/MusicLibrary\/Musics\/1989 - Streetcleaner\/folder.jpg"}}`

Now this is making me even more confused as i can see that the json is formatted properly. Please provide any sort of suggestion on how to solve this problem.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Are you prefixing a `<!DOCTYPE HTML>` to your JSON response?

Comment: 1. you should no have that HTML doctype in your JSON response; 2. you should not print local paths to files, but URLs.

Comment: The response is sent as a string, not a Javascript object. See my answer below.

Comment: I didn't see you set dataType. You may want to create an error: function that lets you know if something went wrong. And if you're getting `200 OK`, the success: should work. As I stated down below, you could try setting dataType to 'text' and alert(data) on success just to see what is coming back.

Comment: @techfoobar no the json is made with this nested associative array::$this->tags_array = array("success" => true, "message" => array("Album_Name" => $this->row[0], "Album_Art" => $this->row[1]));

Comment: @moonwave99 thats what im trying to figure out as to why i'm getting that HTML doctype in my response

Comment: @MichaelWheeler yes i did that before resorting to complete: event. I had one success: and another error: events to handle the data returned, but to my dismay the success never got fired

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON encoded data is usually not sent like

```
data['message']['Album_Name']);
```

But rather like:

```
data.message.Album_Name;
```

You're calling your results the wrong way. These are not associative arrays anymore but are now objects, as the name JSON (JavaScript Object Notation) suggests.

Comment: That's not how you _send_ JSON data - that how you access a JS object [which could have been deserialized from a JSON string, but that's totally unrelated].

Comment: Well it kinda is; after encoding it it looks more like { "message": { "Album_Name": "..." } }, which would make it objects and not associative arrays (Although in Javascript these are practically the same, but that's a whole different discussion.)

Comment: Bracket notation and dot notation are just two different ways to access same data, bracket one being useful if you want to provide a dynamic key for example.

Comment: What's your point? JSON encoded data are sent as Javascript Objects, not associative arrays; which is how he is trying to treat his data.

data['message']; no longer exists as it did in PHP, but data.message does.

Comment: I see what you mean! I didn't know you could also call your objects like they were arrays. Javascript is one weird language. Thanks for the lesson!

Comment: @BjornSchijff yeah tried alert(data.message.Album_Name) but it still gives TypeError: data.message is undefined
[Break On This Error]  

alert(data.message.Album_Name);    I don't know whats causing this but maybe the jquery is unable to recieve data, and i have no idea on how to solve it

Comment: Well the error describes that data.message is undefined, so it seems that data is fine; but it doesn't contain what you think it should contain. Perhaps you could console.log(data); and see what it actually contains upon success.

Comment: yes this is the correct and working solution... Thanks a lot for this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to parse the json response using

```
data = $.parseJSON(data)
```

Comment: Not necessary if he specified `dataType: JSON` in the ajax req.

Comment: Wow, my bad. Apparently I skipped over that one. I would imagine something is getting echo'd that the OP doesn't want. Might be worthwhile to set dataType to text and `alert(data)` to see what is coming back.

Comment: @MichaelWheeler i did parsed it using $.parseJSON before posting my question, but it didn't helped. Like i said i've spent more than 10 hours on this problem, trying out various workarounds but none worked.

Comment: @MichaelWheeler on setting dataType to 'text' alert(data) gives [object Object] and console.log(data) give :: Object { readyState=4, responseText="<!DOCTYPE HTML>\n\n<!DOCT...tcleaner\/folder.jpg"}}", status=200, more...}

Answer (score 1):

Use success event instead of complete in ajax and we can able to parse JSON encoded data in javascript/jQuery by using JSON.parse

Comment: on doing var res = $.parseJSON(data) and alert(res) i get this:: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character
[Break On This Error]  

return window.JSON.parse( data );                                                                   in the console panel

Comment: use var res = JSON.parse(data); directly

Comment: this is what i get  SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character
[Break On This Error]  

var def = JSON.parse(data);

Comment: than alert you data that you get on response and i am sure your getting some error in response....

Comment: alert(data) gives [object Object]

Comment: yes because in php when you fetch data it gives an array of objects thats why it shows object object...first create an array by passing data in foreach loop and than pass that  encoded array foreach($data as $row){$newArray["fieldname"] = $row["fieldname"];} echo json_encode($newArray);

Answer (score 0):

well after a long period of trauma, i finally found a solution, turns out that i needed to parse the response text and then access the objects, individually. 
Here is the working code

```
list_choice = "A";
content_choice = "Artists";             //globals to store default value

$(document).ready(function() {
$('.list-nav > a').click(function() {
    var ltext = $(this).text();
    list_choice = ltext;
    console.log(ltext+" <------>    ");

    $('#loading').css('visibility', 'visible');

    $.ajax({
        url: 'retrieveFileFront.php',
        data: {type: content_choice, navtext: list_choice},
        type: 'POST'
        dataType: 'json',
        complete: function(data) {

            var res = data.responseText;
            res = res.replace(/<!DOCTYPE HTML>/g, "");
            res = res.trim();

            console.log(res);
            var arr = JSON.parse("[" + res +"]");    //needed to parse JSON object into arrays
            console.log(arr[0].message.Album_Name);
            console.log(arr[0].message.Album_Art);               

            $('#loading').css('visibility','hidden');
        }
    });
    return false;

});
```

This works fine and gives the desired response. Anyways thanks for the help, guys.